# What is a proper AWSJSON?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have used this

```
var jsonData = {"hello": 20};
```

while passing this to graphql query

```
products:jsonData
```

it fails with this error

> Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'input.products' with
> value 'StringValue{value='{hello: 20}'}' is not a valid 'AWSJ

ps help

Answer (score 3):

`AWSJSON` is a [JSON string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html).

EDIT: Appsync accepts *escaped* JSON strings `"{\"hello\":20}"` as valid `AWSJSON`.

```js
var jsonData = "{\"hello\":20}"
```

Comment: Thanks . Still Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'input.products' with value 'StringValue{value='{'hello':20}'}' is not a valid 'AWSJSON'

Comment: Does the error occur if you execute the query directly in the appsync console or postman?   Or is the error specific only to whatever app client you are using?

Comment: I am doing it in the appsync and the within the client. See the answer I posted that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
final jsonEncoder = JsonEncoder();
const JsonEncoder encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
String sta = jsonEncode(encoder.convert(_products));
```

then pass

```
products: $sta
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This will work

`var jsonData="{\n  \"hello\":20}"`